# Highlighting blocks in lua in emacs

Tags: emacs, lua

I use lua mode in emacs to work with lua files .
The lua mode is available  [here](http://www.emacswiki.org/LuaMode)

To determine the beginning and end of larger blocks, I used the block mode available [here](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/LuaBlockMode)
The mode highlights the beginning of the line if I place the cursor at the bottom. However, if the beginning of the line is further up more than a page, then it is not visible on the screen. Scrolling with a mouse upwards to find the highlighted line also does not help.

Is there any emacs code that would take me to the beginning of the code if the cursor is at the end and vice versa OR fold the blocks OR any similar functionality that will help to figure out the beginning and end of blocks in lua

Answer (score 1):

Partial answer:

To find the starting point corresponding to an `end` is relatively simple on the base of the lisp code at your [second link](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/LuaBlockMode):

```lisp
(defun lua-block-goto-corresponding-point ()
  "Jump to corresponding point."
  (interactive)
  (goto-char (lua-block-get-corresponding-point)))

(add-hook 'lua-mode-hook (lambda ()
                 (local-set-key (kbd "C-c C-b")
                        'lua-block-goto-corresponding-point)))
```